# How can I use a const of javascript instead of repeated codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use Code A and get a result as I expected.

But Ifind there are many repeated code in Code A, such as the string `"textAreaInput"` are found in many places.

So I use a  const  `InputID` to store the string `"textAreaInput"` and use the const in many place in Code B, but Code B can't get the correct result, why ?

**Code A**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <script type="text/javascript">      
     </script>    
    <script src="Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/my.js"></script>     
     <link href="Css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
       
    <textarea id="textAreaInput">
         Hello
    </textarea>
 
     <input type=button value="Clear" onclick="clearInput('textAreaInput')">
</asp:Content>
```

**my.js File**

```
function clearInput(inputID) {
    $('#' + inputID).val('')
}
```

**Main.css File**

```
#textAreaInput { 
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
```

**Code B**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <script type="text/javascript">      
        const InputID = "textAreaInput"
     </script>    
    <script src="Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/my.js"></script>     
     <link href="Css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
       
    <textarea id= InputID>       //I rewrite
         Hello
    </textarea>
 
     <input type=button value="Clear" onclick="clearInput(InputID)">        //I rewrite
</asp:Content>



...The same
```

Comment: My guess is the const works fine within the JavaScript code (the onClick event) but can't be used outside of JavaScript to define the id of the text area. Try changing that bit back to a hardcoded value and see if it works.

Comment: You're mixing javascript and HTML - `<textarea id= InputID> ` is HTML, it doesn't know anything about javascript variables.  `clearInput(InputID)` would work, but you'd be better with `clearInput(this)` and change your function accordingly.

Comment: As you're using asp.net, you could use a server-side variable/const rather than a javascript one.

Comment: Thinks.How can i use clearInput(this) and change your function accordingly.

Comment: `onclick="clearInput(InputID)"` -> `onclick="clearInput(this)"` / `function clearInput(el) { $(el).val('') }`